# How to access other container id inside docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a situation in which I have a docker-compose.yml file as follows

```
version: '3'

services:

  database:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=king@1234
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "8110:1433"
    container_name: app_db_con

  api:
    build:
      context: /home/shubham/Employee/EmployeeBackEnd/
    image: app-api:dev
    ports:
      - "8111:5001"
    container_name: app_api_con
    depends_on:
      - database

  web:
    build:
      context: /home/shubham/Employee/EmployeeFrontEnd/
    image: app-ui:dev
    ports:
      - "8112:80"
    container_name: app_web_con
    depends_on:
      - database
      - api
```

I want to access the **database** container id inside my **api** container as an argument. For example the args in below code:

```
  api:
    build:
      context: /home/shubham/Employee/EmployeeBackEnd/
    image: app-api:dev
    args:
      - Database_Server: database_container_id
    ports:
      - "8111:5001"
    container_name: app_api_con
    depends_on:
      - database
```

I am not sure how to achieve this. Please help if there is a different approach as well.

Thank You

Comment: What is the reason for that? is to be able to access it from api server? Docker compose add your services to a network and resolve the name as specified in the docker compose service definition, so if you are inside the `api` container you can just refer to the database as `database` and it will be resolved as the database container.

Comment: args will be used only during build , you can use service names all time for connecting to db, or you can link database to your container as any name you want => links: [database:Database_Server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, with docker-compose, each container is accessible by it's service name defined in the compose file.

For example, in your case, if you want to access the `database` container from the `api`, you'll just have to use its name. You can try it out with this command :

```sh
$ docker container exec -ti [your_api_container] ping database
```

For more information about networking in compose, you can look at the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Comment: Thanks, placing the service name as the db server name worked.